# How to make a Map in HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I want to try making a simple map, one that I can move with the mouse drag, and that have images along the map, like a island for example.
I already know how to get the mouse position. First, I declare a variable, `posX` and assign it to `e.clientX`, and I do the same thing for `e.clientY`.

But I don't know how to detect the mouse click and drag, and "move" the image.

And I don't know how to make an image in the right way, I'm making with a div, and with a background image inside of it, and it's not working, because if I want to place another image, to simulate an island for example or several islands, it just make the background image stay side by side or like I'm doing (width 100% and height 100%), its simple make the background image stay too far from one to another.

Comment: Does your map have to be geographically accurate or does it just need to move an image around inside of the browser window?

Comment: He wouldn't need to be geographically accurate, he would only need move an image within the browser window, it would be for a game.

Comment: There are a lot of interesting animation libraries for JavaScript. 
 I think it would benefit to begin reviewing some of those https://blog.bitsrc.io/11-javascript-animation-libraries-for-2018-9d7ac93a2c59

Comment: Also here is a cool demo built with d3js that is related to "viewing a map" https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6242308

Comment: I could probably just have a map with predefined islands, it would be simpler, but I would still have the question of drawing that map while I move with the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you want an image drag. If you want this, you can use this example I created (note this is implemented in the Canvas API, but you can achieve the same effect using only HTML DOM elements and JS):

```js
const MAP_IMG_URL = "https://i1.wp.com/geoawesomeness.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Mercator.jpg?ssl=1";

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Load the map image
const img = new Image();
img.src = MAP_IMG_URL;

// Set canvas size
canvas.width = 620;
canvas.height = 180;

const state = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  startX: 0,
  startY: 0,
  mouseDown: false,
};

function handleMouseDown(event) {
  state.mouseDown = true;
  state.startX = event.clientX - state.x;
  state.startY = event.clientY - state.y;
}

function handleMouseUp() {
  state.mouseDown = false;
}

function handleMouseMove(event) {
  if (!state.mouseDown) {
    return;
  }
  state.x = event.clientX - state.startX;
  state.y = event.clientY - state.startY;
}

// Event listeners
document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

(function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, state.x, state.y);
})();

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work perfectly, I just need to adjust things to be the way I'm imagining, and then I just need to figure out how to add elements that I can click on.

Comment: What do you need to adjust, e.g. do you need to keep the image within the bounds of the container? If so, let me know and I can update the code accordingly...

Comment: Thanks, but there's no need, i don't want to give you any work. Its just another image that i will put and i have to fully understand whats the code does, to try to do what I said above.